# meaning of graph embedding

Tags: graph-theory

I read an article about community detection and it says: "the algorithm defines an embedding of the graph around the seed set.". seed set is a subgraph S of graph G. I don't understand the meaning of the sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, an embedding is a "drawing" of your graph, that respect its topological space.

A graph embedding is a representation of a graph with no intersections between edges. For example, A planar graph is a graph that has such an embedding onto the plane. The complete graph on 4 vertices (usually named $K_4$) is one example, with the following planar embedding :

[image: planar K4]

A toroidal graph is a graph that has such an embedding onto a torus. For example $K_7$:

[image]

The genus of a graph is the minimum possible genus of the surface onto which it can be embedded.

Comment: ok. so you say it means if we have a k4 that has an intersection. it defines an other graph like that but without any intersections?

Comment: The embedding is only one drawing. It does not define another graph, it defines how to draw it without intersection. For some graph it is possible in the plane, for other you need surfaces with higher genus.

Comment: ok, thanks. i understand